# two-dimensional array java

Tags: java, arrays

Can't understand what I am doing wrong :( I want to fill my array with spaces. But receive a mistake 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    j cannot be resolved to a variable

```
at Field.space(Field.java:11)
at Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

This is my simple code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args){
        Field field = new Field();
        field.space();
    }
}


public class Field {
    private static final int ArraySize = 3;
    private char spacesymbol = ' ';
    private char[][] array = new char [ArraySize][ArraySize];

    public void space() {
        for (int i=0; i<ArraySize; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<ArraySize; j++)
                array[i][j]= spacesymbol;
            System.out.println("[" + array[i][j] + "]");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the braces for the inner for loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<ArraySize; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<ArraySize; j++)
        array[i][j]= spacesymbol;
    System.out.println("[" + array[i][j] + "]"); // 'j' who?
}
```

Without them it will only execute the next line after it (`array[i][j]= spacesymbol;`), and when we do the `System.out.println("[" + array[i][j] + "]");` it will not know which `j` we are talking about.

So the new code will look like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<ArraySize; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<ArraySize; j++){
        array[i][j]= spacesymbol;
        System.out.println("[" + array[i][j] + "]");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot braces for the second for loop, change it to:

```
for (int j=0; j<ArraySize; j++) {
    array[i][j]= spacesymbol;
    System.out.println("[" + array[i][j] + "]");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your second `for` loop does not use curly braces, so it only includes the first statement immediately following the `for` statement. So only the line

```
array[i][j]= spacesymbol;
```

is actually in scope for the variable `j`. The line after that is outside of the `for` loop, so the variable `j` no longer exists. Change your code to this to fix this error:

```
for (int i=0; i<ArraySize; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<ArraySize; j++) {
        array[i][j]= spacesymbol;
        System.out.println("[" + array[i][j] + "]");
    }
}
```

For this reason, I always recommend using the curly braces for any `for` block.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the braces after your second for-loop.

```
public void space() {
  for (int i=0; i<ArraySize; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<ArraySize; j++) {
      array[i][j]= spacesymbol;
      System.out.println("[" + array[i][j] + "]");
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

after the second inner for loop you are missing braces